# How to Interrupt/Abort Rx Java Observable Chain Subscription?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2, reactive

I have a requirement to abort the Rx Java Observable chain, Take Until helps partially but does a graceful completion of Job. I need a handle onAborted on all the the observables part of this chain. Dispose/CompositeDispose none of them are helping to delegate the onAborted handle upward in observable.

Note: The RxJava is not being used here for UI Operations, rather to process/transform shorter data streams in memory.

```
dataObservable.map(row -> convertRow())
                    //.takeUntil(getAbortPredicate()/*return true when abort set to true*/)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .doFinally(getResetAbortAction()/*resets abort flag*/)
                    .blockingGet()
```

The dataObservable itself here is chain of observables. I want to interrupt all such observables involved & get a handle on abort for each of them.

```
public class A {
    private Observable<Row> observable;
    private Boolean aborted;
    private SomeUtilityWithResources utilty
    
    public A(Observable<Row> observable){
        this.observable = observable;
        this.aborted = false;
        this.utilty = SomeUtilityWithResources.Init();
    }
    
    
    
    public A mergeOp1(A aRight){
            Observable<Row> merged = observable.flatMap(lr -> aRight.observable.map(rr -> utilty.merge1(lr.toList(), rr.toList())));
            //When abruptly aborted I want to call utilty.resources.abort().... something like joined.OnAborted(utility.resources.abort())
            //Tried OnDispose()/OnError doesn't get invoked though
            //utilty.merge1 also returns an Observable
            return new A(merged)
    }
    public A mergeOp2(A aRight){
            Observable<Row> merged = observable.flatMap(lr -> aRight.observable.map(rr -> utilty.merge2(lr.toList(), rr.toList())));
            //When abruptly aborted I want to call utilty.resources.abort().... something like joined.OnAborted(utility.resources.abort())
            //Tried OnDispose()/OnError doesn't get invoked though
            //utilty.merge2 also returns an Observable
            return new A(merged)
    }
    public A mergeOp3(A aRight){
            Observable<Row> merged = observable.flatMap(lr -> aRight.observable.map(rr -> utilty.merge3(lr.toList(), rr.toList())));
            //When abruptly aborted I want to call utilty.resources.abort().... something like joined.OnAborted(utility.resources.abort())
            //Tried OnDispose()/OnError doesn't get invoked though
            //utilty.merge3 also returns an Observable
            return new A(merged)
    }
    
    public List<Row> execWay1(){
        observable.map(row -> convertRowWay1())
                    //.takeUntil(getAbortPredicate()/*return true when abort set to true*/)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .doFinally(getResetAbortAction()/*resets abort flag*/)
                    .blockingGet()
    }
    public Long count(){
        observable
            //.takeUntil(getAbortPredicate()/*return true when abort set to true*/)
            .count()
            .doFinally(getResetAbortAction(action.toString()))
            .blockingGet()
    } 
    
    public void abort(){
        this.aborted = true;
    }
    private Action getResetAbortAction(String action) {
        return new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Throwable {
                if (aborted.get()) {
                    aborted.set(false);
                    //LOGGER.error(action + " execution aborted successfully!");
                    //throw new Exception("Aborted")
                }

            }
        };
    }

    private Predicate<T> getAbortPredicate() {
        return new Predicate<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(T t) throws Exception {
                return aborted.get();
            }
        };
    }
}


/* Executor would be calling:

A a = SomeUtilityWithResources.getDefaultObservableFromSomeSource();
a = a.mergeOp1.mergeOp2.mergedOp3
a.count()
//if taking longer.... a.abort() on seperate thread;
a.execWay1();
```

Comment: Why are you using `blockingGet`? Use a regular `subscribe` which you can then get a `Diposable` for or use a 4-arg version to work with a composite too. Where is that `onAborted`?

Comment: I have added a updated the code for better understanding

Comment: `doOnDispose` would be the main way of doing it, but then you'd likely have to use `timeout` or `takeUntil()` with a `Subject` at the very end of the chain to trigger dispose.